# Can you use document.querySelector("abc") in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My problem is getting a "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null at updatePrice" error. I'm wondering if my problem lies in the array of selectors? and if so, is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

```
var currency = "CAD";
var coins = [document.querySelector("#btc"),
            document.querySelector("#eth"),
            document.querySelector("#eos"),
            document.querySelector("#lite")];
var urls = ["https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=EOS&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LITE&tsyms=CAD"];

window.onload = function loadPrices() {
  setInterval(function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        fetch(urls[i])
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(updatePrice, i)
        .catch(displayErrors);
      }
}, 5000);
}

function parseJSON(res) {
  return res.json().then(function(parsedData){
    console.log(parsedData[currency]);
    return parsedData[currency];
  })
}
function updatePrice(data, i){
    console.log(coins[i]);
    coins[i].innerText = data;
 }
function handleErrors(res){
  if(!res.ok){
    throw Error(res.status);
  }
  return res;
}
function displayErrors(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

My output from this code is this, so its definitely looping the URL's properly and retrieving the prices, just not putting them into the right places in my HTML. And the problem is not within the HTML because I can get it to work with the first response if I get rid of the array.

```
9138.95
undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at updatePrice (btc.js:30)
724.17
undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at updatePrice (btc.js:30)
14.19
undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at updatePrice (btc.js:30)
0.001736
undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at updatePrice (btc.js:30)
```

Comment: I bet the divs do not exist at the time you run the loop?

Comment: The direct answer is "yes", but it's not entirely clear what's going on.

Comment: The main problem is this line: `.then(updatePrice, i)`. The variable `i` isn't passed to your `updatePrice` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `let` rather than `var` inside your for loop and [here's why](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/).

Also, your `updatePrice` function wasn't being passed the `i` variable correctly and therefor `coins[i]` was undefined. An easy enough fix is to pass in a function that calls another function. So change:

`.then(updatePrice, i)`

to

`.then((data)=>updatePrice(data, i))`

It might also be useful to review how the [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) function works.

```js
var currency = "CAD";
var coins = [document.querySelector("#btc"),
            document.querySelector("#eth"),
            document.querySelector("#eos"),
            document.querySelector("#lite")];
var urls = ["https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=EOS&tsyms=CAD",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LITE&tsyms=CAD"];

window.onload = function loadPrices() {
  setInterval(function() {
      for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        fetch(urls[i])
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then((data)=>updatePrice(data, i))
        .catch(displayErrors);
      }
}, 5000);
}

function parseJSON(res) {
  return res.json().then(function(parsedData){
    console.log(parsedData[currency]);
    return parsedData[currency];
  })
}
function updatePrice(data, i){
    console.log(coins[i]);
    coins[i].innerHTML = data;
 }
function handleErrors(res){
  if(!res.ok){
    throw Error(res.status);
  }
  return res;
}
function displayErrors(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

```html
<div id="btc"></div>
<div id="eth"></div>
<div id="eos"></div>
<div id="lite"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags need to exist before you get them

```
var coins;
window.onload = function loadPrices() {
  coins = [document.querySelector("#btc"),
           document.querySelector("#eth"),
           document.querySelector("#eos"),
           document.querySelector("#lite")];
```